# How to obtain iframe source using Selenium [Python]

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

So the following HTML looks like this for the iframe

```
<div class="main-iframe-page front-goal-view">
    <iframe src="https://....cpp=44343645233" frameborder="0" style="height: 1304px;"></iframe>
```

There is no 'id' or 'name' for this iframe so i'm not sure how to access this, but is there a way to extract the src?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iframe is an element like any other element , you can use the same logic as you use for anyother element

eg:

```
 frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="main-iframe-page front-goal-view"]/iframe')

 driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

Comment: I managed to get it to work by adding self.driver.switch_to.frame(0) which caught the first iframe it can find. Thank you for the response, I don't know why I didn't think of the way you've done it! i'll give it a try and let you know of the result :)